# JavaFX Event handling from a different class

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller

I looked at the stackoverflow questiions that seem similar to my problem, but none were of any help.

Here is my problem:

For a project, I am making a JavaFX app that is in pure Java without FXML. I have two classes, a controller `Controller` class and a class containing gui stuff `GUI`.

`Controller` has a member variable of type `GUI` and I am trying to assign an event handler to one of the buttons in `GUI` but it doesn't seem to work. It only works when I try implementing the handler inside the `GUI` class, but I need it to work in `Comtroller`.

In the constructor of `Controller` is as follows:

```java
        this.view = view;

        view.addSimpleHandler(new SimpleHandler());
```

`view` is of type `GUI` and `addSimpleHandler` is a member function of `view`

`SimpleHandler` is an inner class of `Controller` that implements EventHandler and overrides the `handle()` function

```java
public void addSimpleHandler(EventHandler<ActionEvent> e) {
        simpleButton.setOnAction(e);
}
```

here is my main method and class signature for `GUI`

```java
public class GUI extends Application {
//member variables for the GUI design including simpleButton
    private Button simpleButton;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI view = new GUI();
        Controller controller = new Controller(view);

        Application.launch(view.getClass(), args);

    }

    public GUI() {
       simpleButton = new Button("Simple button");

       //rest of code is setting up GUI into my panes
    }


    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
        //mainPane is a pane that contains simpleButton with a screenwidth and screenHeight
        primaryStage.setTitle("Simple");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

Comment: Show your whole code.

Comment: @mentallurg this is the only code involved

Comment: Obviously, it is not. For instance, "simpleButton" is not defined. It is hard to help you if it is not clear what code you really have.

Comment: @mentallurg added the simple button part.

Comment: Nobody knows what is going on in your Controller and in SimpleHandler. If you don't show code one can only **guess**. Good luck.

Comment: @mentallurg the code you want me to show is not involved in the problem I'm dealing with. My problem is trying to assign an Event Handler to a button by passing an instance of an inner class from a separate class. The inner class implements EventHandler and does the action I want. However, when trying to pass an instance of it, nothing happens.

Comment: Do not instantiate the application class yourself, an instance will be created as part of the launch process (i.e. `Application#launch`). In other words, you have two instances of `GUI` being created and the one you link with your `Controller` instance is not related to what's displayed on screen. For JavaFX applications, think of `#init()` and `#start(Stage)` as the entry points.

Comment: @Slaw thank you so much for that! My program works now. If you write your comment out as an answer, I'll mark you as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't instantiate your application class manually. To understand why, see [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) regarding the JavaFX life-cycle (**emphasis** mine):

> The entry point for JavaFX applications is the Application class. **The JavaFX runtime does the following**, in order, whenever an application is launched:
>
> 1. Starts the JavaFX runtime, if not already started (see `Platform.startup(Runnable)` for more information)
> 2. **Constructs an instance of the specified Application class**
> 3. Calls the `init()` method
> 4. **Calls the `start(javafx.stage.Stage)` method**
> 5. Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:
>
>    - the application calls `Platform.exit()`
>    - the last window has been closed and the `implicitExit` attribute on `Platform` is true
> 6. Calls the `stop()` method

As you can see, JavaFX itself will instantiate the application class and it's *that* instance which has its life-cycle methods invoked—those methods being `init()`, `start(Stage)`, and `stop()`. However, in your code you have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI view = new GUI(); // created your own instance
    Controller controller = new Controller(view); // gave controller that instance

    // Launches JavaFX which starts the life-cycle documented above
    Application.launch(view.getClass(), args);
}
```

You create your own instance of `GUI`. This instance is not managed by JavaFX which means its `start(Stage)` method is never invoked. When you create the `Controller` instance and pass it your instance of `GUI` you're adding the `EventHandler` to a node which is never displayed. The window you see displayed is from the `GUI` instance created as part of the call to `Application#launch` and that `GUI` instance is never associated with a `Controller`.

For JavaFX applications you should consider the `init()` and `start(Stage)` methods as the entry points<sup>1</sup>. In other words, create the `Controller` in one of those aforementioned life-cycle methods. Although I suppose you could do the same in the constructor instead<sup>2</sup>. Whichever you choose, take note of which thread invoke each method, which is documented [in the same place as the life-cycle](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html). Here are the essentials:

- The application class is loaded, initialized, and constructed on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.
- The `init()` method is invoked by the *JavaFX-Launcher* thread.
- The `start(Stage)` and `stop()` methods are invoked by the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

Remember that certain actions can only be executed on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

---

<sup>1. You can still execute code before the call to `Application#launch` within the main method if needed. The only constraint is that code should not be directly related to JavaFX.</sup>

<sup>2. Your constructor is currently public and has zero parameters—keep it that way. JavaFX requires the application class to have a public, no-argument constructor in order to construct an instance via reflection.</sup>